# OpenCL on Android >= API 23

Tags: android-ndk, opencl

I want to know how android nougat dynamic linkage restrictions will affect using opencl libraries provided by vendors in newer (in api 24 any dynamic linkage except linking to ndk public libraries will fail) android versions ?